# Querying on the extra parameter in a Many to May relationship with extra parameters

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I am struggling mightily with this. Here is a simplified model. Books can have many authors ... Authors can have participated in many books, and that participation can be that of a 'writer', 'illustrator' or 'other'

This is how I have my model:

```
class Book(Base):
    __tablename__ = "book"

    book_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    title = Column(VARCHAR(128))
    authors = relationship("Author", secondary="book_author", back_populates='books')


class Author(Base):
    __tablename__ = "author"

    author_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(VARCHAR(128))
    books = relationship("Book", secondary="book_author", back_populates='authors')


class Book_Author(Base):
    __tablename__ = "book_author"

    book_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Book.book_id), primary_key=True)
    author_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Author.author_id), primary_key=True)
    role = Column(VARCHAR(128))  # Let's say it can be 'writer', 'illustrator', 'other'
```

I can do the CRUD basics.

Simple query of books:

```
session.query(models.Book).all()
```

Returns all books with an embedded list of authors for each book.

But where I struggle is a query where I want all books listing the authors, but only authors's whose role='writer'

I have spent hours searching for this and trying many different things but cannot get it to work.

EG:

```
session.query(models.Book).filter(models.Book_Author.role == 'writer').all()
```

Still returns all authors of a book.

I have tried various different query.options - selectinload, with_loader_criteria etc. I did not fully understand their usage but could not get anything to work right.

If anyone has any suggestions it would be greatly appreciate.

```
session.query(models.Book).filter(models.Book_Author.role == 'writer').all()
```

I was expecting only authors whose role was a writer to be returned.

Comment: You need to join your book authors in query and then filter by role. Read the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/select.html#joins)

Answer (score 0):

To get authors, you should formulate a query that returns them directly. The ability to ask all authors about the relationship based on the book is not filtered by role.

In order to filter for a property from the join table, it is necessary to join the tables beforehand. This means that the entries are queried based on the match of the ID columns. You can then filter by the property.

So the question should start with the Author table, followed by a join to the join table and filtering by role. With the following query you get all authors who have taken on the role of the writer.

```py
session.query(models.Author)\
    .join(models.Book_Author)\
    .filter(models.Book_Author.role == 'writer')\
    .all()
```

Comment: I have tried this, and it does not seem to work as intended.

What it does, is it will return any Book that has at least one author with a role = 'writer'

But then, the relationship established in the model seems to attach all authors of a book to that book object.

It is like the relationship in the model cannot be altered.

Comment: I'm sorry it doesn't give the desired result. This query is only based on the relationships through ForeignKeys and ignores the relationships defined in the model. It delivers all authors whose role corresponds to "writer", no books. You are correct that the `relationship` attributes will not help you with your query. You need at least one join statement to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up. I could not find a way to  get this to work.

My workaround is to return all and then apply filtering via python.

This works for my current situation, but does not scale well.